# Geb giving org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException:

Tags: selenium, cucumber, appium, geb, pageobjects

I have updated geb core to **compile "org.gebish:geb-core:0.10.0"** from that time I am getting below error

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 
Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

for code

```
static content = {
        welcomeMessage {$("welcome_message")} // here occurs error org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException:  
    }
```

"$("welcome_message")" is the element which I am not finding but it is shown on screen. I followed geb syntax it is looking same.

I tried with following syntax but still it is not working

1. welcomeMessage {$(".welcome_message")}
2. welcomeMessage {$("welcome_message")}
3. welcomeMessage {$("#welcome_message")}
4. welcomeMessage {$("--#welcome_message")}

Comment: try to change selector method !

Comment: And how about using the current version 1.1.1 instead of a very old version?

Comment: I thought that when using a class selector, each class must me prepended with a '.' so your example should read $(".welcome_message") correct?

Comment: @Emna I am not getting "try to change selector method ! "

Comment: @kriegaex I tried with update but it is not working

Comment: @Doug Clark it is not working

Comment: Share [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), please. Do you really think that one line of static content enables others to help you if you don't even take time to describe the problem in an understandable way?

Comment: Please post the HTML of the element. Your examples 1 and 3 indicate to me that you don't understand the difference between using ID and css classes as selectors.

Comment: Are you by any chance using Appium? Did you update anything else apart from Geb, i.e. Selenium? Can you share the full stacktrace that you are getting?